# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'control': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, runtime-error, microsoft-ajax

I am Developing a web application by using ASP.NET 3.5, jQuery and RadAjax Telerik Control. I get  Error Messages when page Loading. that is :"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'control': object is null or undefined" . Image:[image]

and when I click to Open RadWindow then get same Error Message. and could not open radwindow.

Image 2:[image]

How can I solved this Error. Help me..

Thanks 
Nahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the source of the issue can't really be seen with this kind of error message. I would go over to Telerik.com and submit a runnable project, as well as steps to reproduce the issue, in a support ticket and have the support team take a look at the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is isolated to the ***jQuery Validate Javascript Library***.

The script filename is: ***jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js***

Although jQuery is Open Source, this library was ***provided by Microsoft*** (as indicated at the top of my js file):

```
/*
** Unobtrusive validation support library for jQuery and jQuery Validate
** Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*/
```

Try replacing the library to use the replacement ***jquery.validate.min.js***

> One way is to use ***Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager*** by the
>   following:
>
> 1. Right-click on your Project's ***References*** folder
> 2. Select ***'Add Library Package Reference...'***
> 3. When the window opens, Select ***'Online'*** from the left sidebar menu.
> 4. On the top-right, type in ***'jquery.validate'*** and hit the enter key.
> 5. Locate the ***'jQuery Validation'*** and click the ***'Install'*** button.
> 6. Change your code to use the new library name ***'jquery.validate.min.js'***

I tested this and my client-side field validation all seems to work without the annoying exceptions when debugging in Visual Studio.