# datepicker not working after loading page via ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using asp.net mvc 2 with jquery 1.10.1 and jquery ui 1.10.3.

When I'm loading a page with $.ajax, the datepicker is a bit off. It will pop up and go back away just as usual, but the interaction with it is broken.

For example: I click the input => datepicker pops up => select a date => error that currentdate is undefined

A page can have multiple inputs with datepickers, which is why I'm using a .each in my code.

I have 2 pages: Index.aspx and PatchDef.aspx. Index uses a $.ajax call to load in PatchDef.aspx dynamically.

In PatchDef.aspx I am using a  tag with $(document).ready code which binds the datepickers to my inputs.

Here's the code that I'm using right now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datePickerPatchDef").each(function () {
                    var dateFormat = $(this).attr("dateFormatPatchDef").toLowerCase();
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: dateFormat,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true
                    });
   });
});
```

I have also tried the following code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415614/datepicker-not-working-in-ajax-loaded-page) :

NOTE: here a class will be something like dpCount1; dpCount2, ...

```
$(".datePickerPatchDef").each(function () {
                var dateFormat = $(this).attr("dateFormatPatchDef").toLowerCase();
                $(this).datepicker({
                var dpCountClass;
                var allClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(' ');

                for (var i = 0; i < allClasses.length; ++i) {
                    var singleClass = allClasses[i];
                    if (singleClass.match("^dpCount")) {
                        dpCountClass = "." + singleClass;
                    }
                }

                $("#switchUser").text(dpCountClass);
                $("body").on("focusin", dpCountClass, function () {
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: dateFormat,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true
                    });
                });
            });
        }
```

I thought the second try would solve the dynamic loading, but it just doesn't.

The exact error I'm getting is:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property
>   'currentDay': object is null or undefined

and it goes to the code

```
o.selectedDay=o.currentDay=t("a",n).html()
```

where o = undefined

So if you have any suggestions, I can always use them.
If you need additional information, please ask!

Comment: Thank you for the mysterious downvote without explanation. It completely helps people with questions to get answers.

Comment: Have you tried putting the code inside the ajax.success function?

Comment: @dops Yes, I have tried that. It gives the exact same problem.

Comment: Where is this code?  In index.apsx or in PatchDef.aspx? Also could we see the full ajax request?

Comment: Index.aspx contains the $.ajax with the success function. It gives back the PatchDef.aspx page which includes the jquery code that I have provided in my question. As you suggested I hav also tried to move my datepicker code from PatchDef.aspx to the Index ajax.success, but that produced thesame error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've posted what I think is an answer, also keep the code inside index.aspx.  I think that is better

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812784/jquery-datepicker-wont-work-on-a-ajax-added-html-element

Answer (score 2):

I Faced The Same Issue, This Works For Me.
Hope This Helps

Before The Ajax Call Disable All The Datepickers

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker("destroy"); 
$(".datePicker").removeClass("hasDatePicker"); 
$(".datePicker").removeAttr("Disabled");
```

And After The Ajax Call Which Can Add or remove DOM Elements
Then Re-Initialize The Datepicker

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", showOn: "focus" });
```

And You Must Call this Also .... This is Very Important As This Will Rebind The JQuery DOM

```
jQuery.datepicker.dpDiv.appendTo(jQuery('body'));
```

```js
  var RemoveJQUIDatepicker = function () {
 
   
   
 $(".datePicker").datepicker("destroy");
 $(".datePicker").removeClass("hasDatePicker");
 $(".datePicker").removeAttr("Disabled");
   
};


var SetJQUIDatePicker = function () {
   
 $(".datePicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  showOn: "focus"
  
 });

   
 
 jQuery.datepicker.dpDiv.appendTo(jQuery('body'));
   
}

//example Ajax Call Sequence
RemoveJQUIDatepicker();
 $.ajax({

  url: initURL,
  type: "Get",
  success: function (data) {
   
   SetJQUIDatePicker();
    //Do Something
   

  },
  error: function () {
   //Do Something
   SetJQUIDatePicker();

  }


 });
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me.
I destroyed the datepicker from the class, created new datepicker function and called it in success response. And it worked.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was just stupid, stupid, stupid. I have just done virtually the same thing.

It is a scope/context problem. Once you are in the each function you lose the $(this) context to that function ie $(this) now refers to the function not the objects your selector returns.

Luckily '.each()' helps you by being able to pass the individual objects to the function.

```
$.ajax({
    url:        'patchdef.php',
    type:       "GET",
    dataType:   "html",
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        // LOADING
    },
    success:    function( data ) {
        area.html(data);
        $(".datePickerPatchDef").each(function (key, PatchDef) {
            var dateFormat = $(PatchDef).attr("dateFormatPatchDef").toLowerCase();
            $(PatchDef).datepicker({
                dateFormat: dateFormat,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I am 95% sure that this will work for you. Also I upvoted your question to make it a wash :)

EDIT: I think you can keep this in index.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still gives thesame error. Also a note: I have to use $(PatchDef) to use .attr and .datepicker. As you have suggested in your edit, I also tried it in my Index.aspx, which still produces thesame result.

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens - $(PatchDef), of course. I was being dumb again. But now I'm lost as to why it doesn't work. If I was trying to solve this on my project then I would be using console.log on everything. I'm sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: No need to apologize. I'm already happy you tried to help me. I'm guessing I'm missing some specific case. Right now I'm just hoping this doesn't end up on the pile of unsolved bugs. :)

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens I just mocked it up on my server and got it to work!  Use my function above (with your $(PatchDef) edit) and stick it inside the success callback of the ajax query. Worked for me :)

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens I've edited my answer above to show you my full code.  Please note I use php so obviously the filenames are wrong :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I keep getting thesame error message everytime. My $.ajax call is identical to yours except for the url ofcourse and the fact that I don't use a beforeSend. I'm just hoping it doesn't have anything to do with browser support now, as I'm developing this for IE9.

Comment: Me too, I used firefox

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: jquery 1.10.1 and jquery ui 1.10.3

Comment: How so? Version 1.X has support for ie 6+ and as far as I know 9 > 6, so it should work.

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens no, you're right. I have lost the ability to read it seems :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404850/3501422 - seems to be the same issue you are running into

Comment: I've checked it out and we're not using the jquery validations nor are we using Telerik. It seems I'm having a different problem.